# Fire event when different parts of image is clicked - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications

I would like to open another image when certain portion/part of current image is opened.

For Example:

Image 1 : Human Face - there will be points on the image like one for eye , one for ear , one for mouth.

When user clicks on eye a new image should open ( which will be an enlarged eye which will show more details ).

Can someone please give me few tips on how to proceed with this application?

Thanks

Comment: Use an image map. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/map

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use map tag - here is simple example http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

You can also use javascript to handle that.

jQuery adds event.pageX,event.pageY when you get your image position by jquery position it`s easy to calculate triggered position.